# Pragmas seem to work differently than I expect in Seaside

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

Fairly new to Pharo/Seaside and it has been a long time since I used Smalltalk. I am trying to make a RESTful service and can not get it to work using the pragmas the way I think it should. Ie here is my list method within class TeamMembers which is a direct subclass of WARestfulHandler.

```
list
   <get>

^ String streamContents: [ :stream |
    self teamMembers do: [ :each |
       stream nextPutAll: each ; crlf ] ]
```

After doing all the proper registration 
    WAAdmin register: TeamMembers at: 'team-members'
when I execute in the browser (http://localhost:8080/team-members) I received the message

/team-members not found
but if I execute (http://localhost:8080/team-members/list), it works as expected.

This seems to contradict the documentation in http://book.seaside.st/book/advanced/restful/getting-started/define-handler.

If I override the TeamMembers>>

```
createRoutes
    | route |
    route := WARoute get: '/listJson' selector: #listJson.
    ^OrderedCollection new
        "GET"
        add: route; 
        add: (WARoute get: #list); 
        yourself
```

Then I get the expected behaviour when I browse to (http://localhost:8080/team-members)

However, to get the Json output I still have to use (http://localhost:8080/team-members/listJson).

I have probably missed something pretty simple but any help is appreciated.

Using Pharo6.0-64.image with Seaside and this is how seaside was installed.

```
Metacello new
  configuration:'Seaside3';
  repository: 
 'http://www.smalltalkhub.com/mc/Seaside/MetacelloConfigurations/main';
  version: #stable;
  load.


Gofer new
  squeaksource: 'Seaside30Addons';
  package: 'Seaside-REST-Core';
  package: 'Seaside-Pharo-REST-Core';
  package: 'Seaside-Tests-REST-Core';
  load.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `<path: '/'>` pragma because you have more than one method with `<get>` pragma and no arguments.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that adding another pragma to the list method has solved the problem.

```
list
   <get>
   <path: '/'>

   ^ String streamContents: [ :stream |
        self teamMembers do: [ :each |
           stream nextPutAll: each ; crlf ] ]
```